# Nodejs app not working on Windows. The same app works on Ubuntu

Tags: node.js, windows, express

I have an app that works on Ubuntu but not works on Windows 8.1. All the packages are installed. Below is the stack trace.

```
info: Error app.js TypeError: Cannot read property 'authError' of undefined
What up
GET /getRelatasHeaders 304 24ms
GET /getRelatasSocialAccounts 304 5ms
GET /relatas/error/checkAuthError 500 96ms
GET /images/favicon.ico 200 18ms - 427b
info: uncaughtException: message: socket hang up stack: {"code":"ECONNRESET"}
info: uncaughtException: message: socket hang up stack: {"code":"ECONNRESET"}
info: uncaughtException: message: socket hang up stack: {"code":"ECONNRESET"}
info: uncaughtException: message: socket hang up stack: {"code":"ECONNRESET"}
info: Relatas Error Report Message sent: 250 2.0.0 OK 1459823394 ez6sm3325430pab.12 - gsmtp
info: Error: socket hang up
    at createHangUpError (_http_client.js:200:15)
    at TLSSocket.socketOnEnd (_http_client.js:292:23)
    at emitNone (events.js:72:20)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:166:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:913:12)
    at nextTickCallbackWith2Args (node.js:442:9)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (node.js:397:17)
info: Relatas Error Report Message sent: 250 2.0.0 OK 1459823395 o7sm42402626pfa.37 - gsmtp
info: Error: socket hang up
    at createHangUpError (_http_client.js:200:15)
    at TLSSocket.socketCloseListener (_http_client.js:232:23)
    at emitOne (events.js:82:20)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:169:7)
    at TCP._onclose (net.js:477:12)
info: Relatas Error Report Message sent: 250 2.0.0 OK 1459823396 v3sm3310766par.17 - gsmtp
info: Error: socket hang up
    at createHangUpError (_http_client.js:200:15)
    at TLSSocket.socketOnEnd (_http_client.js:292:23)
    at emitNone (events.js:72:20)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:166:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:913:12)
    at nextTickCallbackWith2Args (node.js:442:9)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (node.js:397:17)
info: Relatas Error Report Message sent: 250 2.0.0 OK 1459823396 f12sm42381773pfd.87 - gsmtp
info: Error: socket hang up
    at createHangUpError (_http_client.js:200:15)
    at TLSSocket.socketCloseListener (_http_client.js:232:23)
    at emitOne (events.js:82:20)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:169:7)
    at TCP._onclose (net.js:477:12)
```

I tried updating some of the modules but that didn't work too.
I'm running Nodejs 4.4.2 and Express 4.0

Comment: What is the version of node ? maybe there's a problem with TLS and windows in old versions like 0.12 (I'm not sure).

Comment: I actually tried a new instllation on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I get the same error on Ubuntu too.